# Random Number Generator using Geometric Distribution

Tags: c#, .net, random, distribution, mathnet-numerics

I need a random number generator using a geometric distribution

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Distribution.

I tried `MathNet.Numerics.Distributions`:

```
public void GeometricTest()
{
    var geometric = new Geometric(0.1);
    int back = geometric.Sample();
    Assert.Greater(back, -1);
}
```

But the test gives just negative numbers. Does somebody spot my mistake or give me advice for other ways of sampling a geometric distribution?

Comment: Don't have time to really dig into it but this might answer your question: [link](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/discussions/529797)

Comment: can you show the implementation of Sample function?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the bug. The new version is apparently not yet on nuGet. Maybe, I just add a minus sign ...

Comment: This was fixed in v3.0.0-alpha8 and is also included in the (as of today newest) v3.0.0-beta01 package on NuGet. Until v3.0 final, NuGet only lists them if you enabled pre-release packages though.

Comment: For a more general approach to the problem see http://ericlippert.com/2012/02/21/generating-random-non-uniform-data/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To generate a geometric with probability `p` of success on each trial, given a function `rand` which returns a uniform(0,1) result, pseudocode is:

```
define geometric(p)
  return ceiling(ln(1-rand) / ln(1-p))
```

This yields how many trials until the first success.  If you want the alternate definition of a geometric (how many failures prior to the first success) subtract 1 or use `floor` instead of `ceiling`.